# Usando Transaction Scope con 2 base de datos distintas

Tags: c#, sql-server, transacciones

Necesito hacer una transaccion entre dos base de datos, al insertar datos en una tabla en la Base de datos A necesito insertar datos tambien en la Base de datos B, pero si falla la base de datos B necesito hacer un rollback en la base de datos A tambien, me base en el siguiente codigo:

```
private static void ExecuteTwoMethodsOpeningTwoConnections(string connectionString) {
    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        ExecuteCommandA(connectionString);
        ExecuteCommandB(connectionString);

        Console.WriteLine(“Both records are written to database transactionally.”);
        scope.Complete();
    } }


private static void ExecuteCommandA(string connectionString) {
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();

        command.Connection = connection;

        command.CommandText = “Insert into MyTable(ColumnA, ColumnB) VALUES (1234, ‘ValueB’)”;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    } }

private static void ExecuteCommandB(string connectionString) {
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();

        command.Connection = connection;

        command.CommandText = “Insert into MyTable(ColumnA, ColumnB) VALUES (5678, ‘Another Value’)”;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    } }
```

Primero recibi un error de que no estaba activaado el MSDTC, lo active y despues recibo el siguiente error:

'The partner transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions.'

Como puedo solucionarlo o tal vez no es posible hacer una transaction usando diferentes conexiones a diferentes base de datos?

Comment: No necesitas crear 2 conexiones a servers distintos, tendrías que enlazar 1 servidor con el otro para que el Servidor 1 conozca las bases de datos y objetos (tablas, procedures, functions) del Servidor 2. Busca información acerca de "LinkedServers" en SQLServer

Comment: Creo que no me serviria, las dos conexiones usan el mismo server pero distinta base de datos.

Answer (score 1):

Si son dos base de datos que estan en el mismo servicio es aun mas facil porque no necesitas likearlas, podrias en un procedure actualizar las tablas de ambas dbs y definir alli la transaccion

Desde tu codigo solo invocas al procedure de una de estas, la cual definas como princial y la actualizacion se aplicara en ambas

[Query against two tables in separate databases on the same server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944373/query-against-two-tables-in-separate-databases-on-the-same-server)

Es tan simple como usar el nombre de la db cuando operas con esta, si en un procedure haces algo como esto

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ProcedureEjemplo
    @val1 nvarchar(50),   
    @val2 nvarchar(50)
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;  

    BEGIN TRAN;
    BEGIN TRY

        INSERT INTO dbo.Table1 (campo1, campo2) 
          VALUES (val1, val2)

        INSERT INTO Database2.dbo.Table2 (campo1, campo2) 
          VALUES (val1, val2)

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

       IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
          ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

    END CATCH
END
```

valida como el segundo insert define el nombre de la db, si esta en el mismo servicio con eso alcanza

Nota: cuando dices `dbo` seria el schema, puede ser ese o el que definas

Comment: Y como lo haria para llamar la connectionString? ya que un campo lleva el nombre de una base de datos o no importa?

Comment: solo vas a necesitar un unico connection string, el de la db que define el procedure para poder ejecutarlo, la otra se actualiza por medio del procedure que es donde actualiza la tabla de esa db y de la otra. Es el procedure el que define la transaccion

Comment: oh ya, queria evitar todo eso por que es bastante grande lo que quiero insertar ademas de tener que hacer un ciclo for para una lista que contiene un objeto y no tengo un numero fijo de cuantos objetos tendra esa lista, dejare como plan b eso que me dices si no logro hacer que funcione el transactionscope, gracias.

Comment: Si necesitas pasar una lista al procedure puede usar los `table valued parameters` https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tienes es un detalle que te falta en tu configuración:

Ingresa a :

Panel de control > Todos los elementos de Panel de control > Herramientas administrativas > Servicio de Componentes

Abres el Nodo hasta Coordinador de Transacciones Distribuidas y en el objeto DTC Local das click derecho e ingresas a las propiedades, ve a la pestaña Seguridad y verás la imagen a continuación, copia los parámetros para que se vea igual a la imagen.

Esta configuración debe ser aplicada a ambos equipos Cliente y Servidor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez realizado el paso podemos ir a verificar el código.

Partiendo desde el concepto de transacción y comprendiendo que teniendo un comportamiento ideal donde o todo se cumple o nada se modifica que vendría a ser el Commit y Rollback. Es necesario que verifiques cada paso de tu transacción.

Yo hice algo simple pero te puede ayudar a esclarecer un poco las ideas.

```
private static void ExecuteTwoMethodsOpeningTwoConnections(string connectionString)
{
      //Crea una nueva transacción
      using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
      {
           //introduzco una forma de validación para controlar que se haya completado 
           int validate = 0;

           validate += ExecuteCommandA(connectionString);
           validate += ExecuteCommandB(connectionString);

           if (validate == 2)
           {
                Console.WriteLine("Both records are written to database transactionally.");
                scope.Complete();
           }

           scope.Dispose();
       }
}


private static int ExecuteCommandA(string connectionString)
{
       int result = 0;

       using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
       {
           connection.Open();

           SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();

           command.Connection = connection;

           command.CommandText = "Insert into MyTable(ColumnA, ColumnB) VALUES(1234, ‘ValueB’)";
           result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }

      return result;
 }

 private static int ExecuteCommandB(string connectionString)
 {
      int result = 0;

      using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
      {
          connection.Open();

          SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();

          command.Connection = connection;

          command.CommandText = "Insert into MyTable(ColumnA, ColumnB) VALUES(5678, ‘Another Value’)";
          result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }

      return result;
 }
```

Espero que te haya servido.

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias, hice eso en mi computadora pero el server tiene otra configuracion, lo checare.

Comment: Con la novedad de que ya aplique la misma configuracion para las dos maquinas y tengo el firewall desactivado y aun me marca un error: "The MSDTC transaction manager was unable to pull the transaction from the source transaction manager due to communication problems. Possible causes are: a firewall is present and it doesn't have an exception for the MSDTC process, the two machines cannot find each other by their NetBIOS names, or the support for network transactions is not enabled for one of the two transaction managers. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004D02B)"

Comment: y si le seleccionas cambias de autenticación mutua a No requiere autenticación en la configuración del MSDTC en ambos equipos?

Comment: jtaborga, si, tengo esa de No requiere autenticacion en las dos maquinas y aun asi, yo creo que lo implementare sin rollback mientras encuentro una solucion.